# No storage space left

Tags: internal-storage

Long story short, on a R11Max* (?) device with MT6592 CPU running Android 5.1 and reported 8GB storage (though possible to use SD card), when trying to install additional apps than the ones than came at purchase, always shown dialog that there is no storage space left, yet there is plenty left, even when SD card is inserted and is selected prefered install location default write disk.

Though taking pictures or videos with the camera works, so storage is not full.

Of course, from a generic/unbranded device, expectations are much lower, for example there was no fire while charging, fingers crossed!

Any suggestions?

- from Wish.com, was advertised as AllCall Rio Android 7.0, so yea...

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete caches and junk files using third party cleaning apps. The one I use: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You can manually delete cache or app data using settings. Under Manage Apps, click any app and select clear data or cache. Warning: The apps data will be lost. So you will have to start a fresh.

Restart your phone, this will close all the apps running in the background.

If your using an instant messaging app. Delete sent images, videos, documents and audio's. Instant Messaging apps creates a duplicate of the media that you have sent. The send folder is located under the apps folder on your internal storage.

Delete your browser data

Answer (score 0):

Well, someone over at

arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1423733 and
arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=142619

did a (very) thorough invwestigation, and they found out that on this particular device, there is way less space than reported, so there is not much else that can be done